# Python: Which will take less memory and execution is fast?

Tags: python

I have a ResponseMessageService() class, Which have several methods.
I need only one method.

Then Which is better?

call that method directly? by

```
    ResponseMessageService().WrongRegMsg(data="Your Reg ID is wrong!")
```

or take a object

```
    response_message_service = ResponseMessageService()
```

Then call

```
    response_message_service.WrongRegMsg(data="Your Reg ID is wrong!")
```

Which will took less memory and execution is first?

Comment: Better make it a static or class method then, there's no point of instantiating the class here. Execution wise both are going to be almost the same, the only difference is first one doesn't have any references, so it will be garbage collected.

Comment: Do you have *actual* memory or speed problems? If not, choose the one that is most legible and maintainable. If you do, find the real memory/speed problems and don't guess. Premature optimization is bad.

Comment: Thanks @AshwiniChaudhary. "garbage collected" means it will auto deleted from memory after execution? Right? And another thing. Is it load others methods of that class in memory?

Comment: Thank You  @BartFriederichs

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question,

```
ResponseMessageService().WrongRegMsg(data="Your Reg ID is wrong!")
```

would likely to take less memory.

Assigning the instance to a variable makes it retained in the memory, at least until the variable's name is unbound, for example, by using `del response_message_service`

Comment: Thank You so much @btquamto

Comment: Your function seems to be independent to the class, so I recommend to put it into a separate utility module, something like `error_handler.wrong_reg_message(data="Your Reg ID is wrong")`